# how to call method every hour automatically in background in android?

Tags: android, service, background-process

I have create one Android project with Service it working fine but i create some updation like one method call every Hour automatically if application running or not.
 i put the code of Service class and service start from mainActivity class.

```
public class LocationService extends Service  {//uses Main thread not create in another thread.
int mTime ;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Create Service",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mTime = 1;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.d("Service","onStartCommand") ;
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Start Service",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   /* Intent mIntent = intent ;
    String msg = mIntent.getStringExtra("msg")*/
   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onStart Command Service",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message is = "+intent.getStringExtra("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent
            .getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // Start service every hour
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            600 * 1000, pintent);//1000*60 = minute
    Date date = new Date();
    mTime++;
    if(mTime >=25000)
        mTime = 1 ;
    String mDate = date.toString() ;
    DeptTable mDeptTable = new DeptTable(mTime,
            mDate);

    new AsyncDept().execute(mDeptTable);

    Log.e("Service","onStartCommand") ;

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Destroy Service",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

protected class AsyncDept extends
        AsyncTask<DeptTable, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(DeptTable... params) {
        RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
        try {

            api.AddDepartmentDetails(""+params[0].getNo(),
                    params[0].getName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("AsyncCreateUser", e.getMessage());

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    }

}
```

}

in this above code method call but unrealistic time so any solution please tell me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            600 * 1000, pintent);//1000*60 = minute
```

**`to`**

```
 alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            60 * 60 * 1000, pintent);//This makes hour
```

Comment: i will try your suggestion but reapedly call the method onStartCommand i dont know how>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class based on threads:

```
public class OBSynkSchedule extends Thread {

  private static OBSynkSchedule instance = null;
  private int sleepTime = -1;
  private boolean keepRunning = false;

  private OBSynkSchedule() {
  }

  public static OBSynkSchedule get() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new OBSynkSchedule();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public static void startManager() {
      OBSynkSchedule mng = get();
      mng.keepRunning = true;
      mng.start();
  }

  public static void stopManager() {
      OBSynkSchedule mng = get();
      mng.keepRunning = false;
      mng.interrupt();
  }

  public void run() {

     sleepTime = Config.getSleepTime();
     if (sleepTime == -1) {
        // default sleep time 2 hours
        sleepTime = 120;
     }
     // in minutes -> sleepTime x (60000 milisec)
     sleepTime = sleepTime * 60000;
     int i = 1;
     while (keepRunning) {
         try {
              try {
                get().DoIt();
              } catch (Exception e) {
          }
          sleep(sleepTime);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          //Log.error("FeedBackSchedule", this, "run", "Failed to check events: ", e); 
      }
  }
 }

  private void DoIt() {
      try{
         OBDBSynk.synchronize();
      }catch(Exception e) {
      //Log.error("removeInactiveDevices", this, "removeInactiveDevices", "An error occorred when getting devices list: ", e); 
      }
  }

}
```